# Visual Studio Code Postgres SQL Connection

Tags: postgresql, visual-studio

I would like to use Visual Studio Code to preform my PostgreSQL queries, and general DB maintenance as an alternative to pgAdmin4. I have read the documentation included with the appropriate extention (PostgreSQL by MS). When I try to Create A New Profile I get the following prompt:

[image: Server Name Prompt]

I am working from an Apple Mac so I attempted localhost at first. That did not work. I tried the ip address of the local computer with the same result. I attempted just giving the name of the DB, but that did not work either. Any suggestions as to what I can try next. I am terrible at spelling and rembering names so I would like some form of IDE support when I am working.

This is the error I get:
`PostgreSQL: Failed to connect: could not translate host name "localhost\Local" to address: nodename nor servname provided, or not known`

Comment: Yes, I can ping local host. The error comes from VSC.

Answer (score 1):

The notation `hostname\instance` is a typical Microsoft SQL Server notation. PostgreSQL doesn't have the concept of instances like MSSQL does. However, PostgreSQL is run in an instance, it just doesn't have a name.

Maybe a simple `localhost:5432` might work.

Then you might have to add or uncomment a line similar to the following in the `pg_hba.conf` file of the PostgreSQL instance:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
local   all             all                                     trust
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think this answer may be slightly better. No idea where I was with my thoughts when I wrote the initial answer.

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation [here](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/ddex.html) Npgsql has a Visual Studio extension (VSIX) which integrates PostgreSQL access into Visual Studio. It allows connecting to PostgreSQL from within Visual Studio's Server Explorer, create an Entity Framework 6 model from an existing database, etc. The extension can be installed directly from [the Visual Studio Marketplace page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RojanskyS.NpgsqlPostgreSQLIntegration).

The VSIX doesn't automatically add Npgsql to your GAC, App.config, machines.config or any other project or system-wide resource. It only allows accessing PostgreSQL from Visual Studio itself.

As [here](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/articles/lightswitch-postgresql.html) you van find out, How to Connect Visual Studio LightSwitch to PostgreSQL with dotConnect for PostgreSQL Data Provider.

As per postgresql documentation [here](https://postgresapp.com/documentation/troubleshooting.html)  Could not translate host name `localhost`, service `5432` to address: nodename nor servname provided, or not known.

```
Usually this error is caused by broken /etc/hosts file. The problem could be a missing localhost entry, syntax errors or incorrect whitespace.

For reference, here is what this file should look like by default on macOS:

##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

For further you ref [here](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/connection-string-parameters.html), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34274836/connecting-to-postgresql-on-visual-studio), [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/QExhLFwzzB8) and [here](http://forums.devshed.com/postgresql-help-21/postgresql-translate-host-name-873179.html)

Comment: The question is about Visual Studio Code, no?

Comment: Yes I had read through that documentation and have a hosts file in /etc. I have added a line called postgres as another user documentation suggested without success.